# CarouFredSel add content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caroufredsel

I try to add content on the fly to a CarouFredSel slider. The content is inserted fine but CourFredSel does not recognize the new content. Is there a way to tell the slider that the slide count has changed?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        items: 4,
        direction: "left",
        responsive: true,
        infinite: false,
        circular: false,
        scroll: {
            items: 2,
            duration: 1000
        },
        next: {
            button: "#slider-button-next",
            key: "right",
            onBefore: function () {
                loadAdditionalContent();
            }
        },
        prev: {
            button: "#slider-button-prev",
            key: "left"
        },
        auto: {
            play: false
        }
    });
});

function loadAdditionalContent () {
    jQuery('#carousel').trigger('insertItem', ['<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200" class="added" />']);
}
```

Here is a fiddle that describes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bg0xyj8k/

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your code:

fix this in jsfidle: use external reference without https: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js

[image]

I did some changes in your code, did not understanding what are you trying to do there.

```
jQuery( "#slider-add-items" ).click(function() {
  loadAdditionalContent();
});

function loadAdditionalContent () {
    id++;
    jQuery('#carousel').trigger('insertItem', ['<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200" class="added" id="'+ id +'" />']);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bg0xyj8k/2/

**UPDATE**
- be more precise when you are asking someting

FIX 1: insert at next click before fist visible element - http://jsfiddle.net/bg0xyj8k/3/

FIX 2: insert on last position of the slider when next clicked - http://jsfiddle.net/bg0xyj8k/4/ - result => infinite next click

Comment: Let me explain the Problem a littel. Then the onBefore Event is thrown i want to add some content to the slider on the fly. Your solution only seems to work if you add the items before any sliding. But it is important for me that i can add content while sliding right (and only right).

So thanks for your support but i think it would be a waste of time to not change the slider libary.

Comment: Stick to this jquery slider, really easy to use, check updated code.

Comment: You could not upvote this answer ... but its working ... thank you really much!